# I use WinEdt and TEXlive on windows 10. I want to use soyombo package

Tags: errors, packages

I am a Mongolian. I use WinEdt and TeX Live on Windows 10. I want to use the `soyombo` package (`\usepackage{soyombo}`) and `\usepackage[cp437de]{inputenc}`. But it does not accept the package and it gives me the following error message in LaTeX:

```
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 \usepackage
                {filecontents}
```

?

Should I use the following commands?

[image]

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.` means that you are loading inputenc twice. Don't do this.

Comment: Please a) don't post just code fragments, but always [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) b) don't post the code as images, like this the code cannot be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Download

```
CTAN/language/mongolian/soyombo.zip
```

Copy contained 7 files as follows:

```
c:/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/soyombo/soyo4tex.pdf
c:/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/soyombo/soyo4tex.tex
c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/public/soyombo/soyombo.mf
c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/public/soyombo/soyombot.mf
c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/soyombo/soyombo.tfm
c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/soyombo/soyombot.tfm
c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/soyombo/soyombo.sty
```

Finally run

```
mktexlsr
```

Comment: Probably soyombo.zip is not contained in TeX Live
because LICENSE is not known.

Comment: c:/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/ not found folder always  a named "local" folder.

Comment: c:/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/ not found folder soyombo, always  a named "local" folder.

Comment: @Bat-erdene Altangerel: If folders don't exist, you have to
create them, with exactly the same names as I wrote.

Comment: One day before the computer shut down after the computer. but The problem still remains . Why? Help me

Comment: If I am WinEdt and TeX Live on Windows 10.  How to solve the problem

Comment: how to manually install Soyombo package for mac os x. Help me